# Send an email (or any message) once and only once inside a retryable operation

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, language-agnostic

I have a program that is charging a user's credit card. The card is charged via a 3rd party API. When I get a response from the 3rd party API, I update the internal representation of the user's balance. Once the user's balance is updated a receipt is sent to the user via email.

There is a small chance that some server error (e.g. unexpected power outage) could occur between charging a user's card and updating the internal representation of their balance. To protect against this, I've made the entire payment process idempotent so it can be retried without double charging the user but will definitely update the user's internal balance. The only issue is with sending the receipt. There is no way (that I can think of) to make this operation idempotent. Currently, I'm sending an email only of the balance update actually changes anything, but of course the server could fail between the balance update and sending the receipt, leading to a situation where the receipt will never be sent. How do people typically address this problem?

I've marked this question as `language-agnostic` because it seems to be a general problem with sending messages, but I'm using Java and AWS's Simple Email Service for this so it would be great to get answers using those technologies.

Comment: I think you create a column in user table isMailSent of bit type.When ever you need to send email,check the isMailSent column.If its yes then dont send else send

Comment: @SpringLearner There could be a failure between updating the database and sending the email so I don't believe your solution provides a guarantee of single delivery.

Comment: dont you use transactions?

Answer (score -1):

When we have done this before, We used a flag in the object that was set when the notification was sent so that the loop wouldnt send the email if the flag had been set for that transaction/id

Comment: But how did you guarantee that setting the flag / sending the email was an atomic operation? That is, how did you guarantee that there would never be a failure between setting the flag and sending the email?

Comment: The method was set to be synchronised but that didnt guarantee, there was such a small chance of the email going and the flag not being set that it was not worth trying to fix, - you set the flag AFTER it was sent so you know if the email was successfully sent.  On another note if you just put it into a DB and had a different process send emails and set the flag then it could be done as a transaction and be atomic guaranteed

Comment: I don't believe that guarantees idempotency. Sending an email is a side effect not controlled by any database, so there is no way a transaction involving an email to be idempotent (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Max Is there any new findings about idempotent email delivery? I'm having the same question.

Comment: One potential way is to `bcc:` an email/server you control and then check the consistency between the DB's flag and that email server. If either say it was sent, don't send.